# Why does this SQL server query produce a Collation Conflict

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a tough time figuring out why this query is producing a collation error in grouping.
I've narrowed it down to a particular case statement. It works one way (with the result as a string) but when I try and substitute a field from another table (which displays just fine on its own mind you) it throws the collation error.

Here is the code that works fine.

```
Declare @StartDate Date = '09/01/2013';
Declare @EndDate Date = Getdate();

With Invoice as (
        SELECT     
         a.DocEntry
        ,a.DocDate
        ,a.CardCode
        ,a.CardName
        ,a.U_CXS_FMST
        ,a.U_CXS_FRST
        ,a.U_DBS1StoreID
        ,CASE
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = 3 then 2
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = 4 then 3
            when a.DocDate >= '08/01/2011' then isnull(U_CXS_FMST,U_DBS1StoreID)
        end as CompleteStores
        ,d.description StoreName
        ,CASE a.U_CXS_FRST
                    WHEN N'Y' THEN 1
                    WHEN N'N' THEN 0
                    ELSE 0
              END [iVend]
        ,     CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(a.U_DBS1StoreID,0)=0 THEN 0
                    WHEN ISNULL(a.U_DBS1StoreID,0)<>0 THEN 1
              END   [DBS]
        ,     CASE a.CardCode
                    WHEN N'C100' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END [Web]
        ,a.NumAtCard
        ,a.U_TransactionID
        ,a.U_SalesSource
        ,s.Name
        ,b.LineNum
        ,b.ItemCode
        ,c.ItemName
        ,c.CstGrpCode
        ,c.U_WebName
        ,c.U_SupplierCatNum
        ,c.CatCode
        ,c.CatName
        ,c.GroupCode
        ,c.GroupName
        ,c.DeptCode
        ,c.DeptName
        ,c.MfcCode
        ,c.Manufacturer
        ,Cast(b.Quantity as INT) Quantity
        ,b.Price
        ,b.PriceBefDi
        ,b.LineTotal
        ,b.GrossBuyPr
        ,a.DocTotal
        --,((Cast(b.Quantity as INT)* b.Price)-(Cast(b.Quantity as INT)*b.GrossBuyPr))/b.GrossBuyPr as MarginPCT

        FROM         
        MonkeySports.dbo.INV1 AS b 
        INNER JOIN 
        MonkeySports.dbo.OINV AS a ON a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
        Inner Join
        dbo.MS_OITM_Categories as c ON b.ItemCode = c.ItemCode
        Inner Join
        [@SALESSOURCE] as s on a.U_SalesSource = s.Code
        left outer join
        CXSRetail.dbo.RtlStore d on 
        CASE
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = '3' then '2'
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = '4' then '3'
            when a.DocDate >= '08/01/2011' then isnull(U_CXS_FMST,U_DBS1StoreID)
        end = cast(d.siteid as Nvarchar)

        Where 
GrossBuyPr > 0.01
and
a.DocDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
) 
,Invoice1 as (
        Select 
         DocEntry
        ,DocDate
        ,CardCode
        ,CardName
        ,U_CXS_FMST
        ,U_CXS_FRST
        ,U_DBS1StoreID
        ,CompleteStores
        ,StoreName
        ,CASE U_CXS_FRST
                    WHEN N'Y' THEN 1
                    WHEN N'N' THEN 0
                    ELSE 0
              END [iVend]
        ,     CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(U_DBS1StoreID,0)=0 THEN 0
                    WHEN ISNULL(U_DBS1StoreID,0)<>0 THEN 1
              END   [DBS]
        ,     CASE CardCode
                    WHEN N'C100' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END [Web]
                    ,CASE
                WHEN iVend = 0 AND DBS = 0 AND Web = 0
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END [Other]   
        ,NumAtCard
        ,U_TransactionID
        ,U_SalesSource
        ,Name
        ,LineNum
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,CstGrpCode
        ,U_WebName
        ,U_SupplierCatNum
        ,CatCode
        ,CatName
        ,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        ,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        ,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        ,DocTotal
        --,MarginPCT

        From Invoice    
        )
,Invoice2 as (      
    SELECT
        --DocEntry
         --DocDate
        --,CardCode
        --,CardName
        --,U_CXS_FMST
        --,U_CXS_FRST
        --,U_DBS1StoreID
        --,CompleteStores
          CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
          End SalesChnl   
          ,Case 
            When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 Then StoreName
            When Web = 1 Then 'Internet'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other' 
         End StoreName
        ,iVend
        ,DBS
        ,Web
        ,Other  
        --,NumAtCard
        --,U_TransactionID
        ,U_SalesSource
        ,Name
        --,LineNum
        --,CstGrpCode
        --,U_WebName
        --,U_SupplierCatNum
        --,CatCode
        ,CatName
        --,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        --,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        --,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        --,MarginPCT
        --,DocTotal         
FROM Invoice1   

--Where GrossBuyPr = 0

Group By
        --DocEntry
        --DocDate
        --,CardCode
        --,CardName
        --,U_CXS_FMST
        --,U_CXS_FRST
        --,U_DBS1StoreID
        --,CompleteStores
        CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
          End    
        ,Case 
            When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 Then StoreName
            When Web = 1 Then 'Internet'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
         End
        ,iVend
        ,DBS
        ,Web
        ,Other  
        --,NumAtCard
        --,U_TransactionID
        ,U_SalesSource
        ,Name
        --,LineNum
        --,CstGrpCode
        --,U_WebName
        --,U_SupplierCatNum
        --,CatCode
        ,CatName
        --,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        --,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        --,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        --,MarginPCT
        --,DocTotal   
        )
Select *
 from Invoice2
```

Yet when I try this code it throws the collation error.

```
    Declare @StartDate Date = '09/01/2013';
Declare @EndDate Date = Getdate();

With Invoice as (
        SELECT     
         a.DocEntry
        ,a.DocDate
        ,a.CardCode
        ,a.CardName
        ,a.U_CXS_FMST
        ,a.U_CXS_FRST
        ,a.U_DBS1StoreID
        ,CASE
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = 3 then 2
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = 4 then 3
            when a.DocDate >= '08/01/2011' then isnull(U_CXS_FMST,U_DBS1StoreID)
        end as CompleteStores
        ,d.description StoreName
        ,CASE a.U_CXS_FRST
                    WHEN N'Y' THEN 1
                    WHEN N'N' THEN 0
                    ELSE 0
              END [iVend]
        ,     CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(a.U_DBS1StoreID,0)=0 THEN 0
                    WHEN ISNULL(a.U_DBS1StoreID,0)<>0 THEN 1
              END   [DBS]
        ,     CASE a.CardCode
                    WHEN N'C100' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END [Web]
        ,a.NumAtCard
        ,a.U_TransactionID
        ,a.U_SalesSource
        ,s.Name
        ,b.LineNum
        ,b.ItemCode
        ,c.ItemName
        ,c.CstGrpCode
        ,c.U_WebName
        ,c.U_SupplierCatNum
        ,c.CatCode
        ,c.CatName
        ,c.GroupCode
        ,c.GroupName
        ,c.DeptCode
        ,c.DeptName
        ,c.MfcCode
        ,c.Manufacturer
        ,Cast(b.Quantity as INT) Quantity
        ,b.Price
        ,b.PriceBefDi
        ,b.LineTotal
        ,b.GrossBuyPr
        ,a.DocTotal
        --,((Cast(b.Quantity as INT)* b.Price)-(Cast(b.Quantity as INT)*b.GrossBuyPr))/b.GrossBuyPr as MarginPCT

        FROM         
        MonkeySports.dbo.INV1 AS b 
        INNER JOIN 
        MonkeySports.dbo.OINV AS a ON a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
        Inner Join
        dbo.MS_OITM_Categories as c ON b.ItemCode = c.ItemCode
        Inner Join
        [@SALESSOURCE] as s on a.U_SalesSource = s.Code
        left outer join
        CXSRetail.dbo.RtlStore d on 
        CASE
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = '3' then '2'
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = '4' then '3'
            when a.DocDate >= '08/01/2011' then isnull(U_CXS_FMST,U_DBS1StoreID)
        end = cast(d.siteid as Nvarchar)

        Where 
GrossBuyPr > 0.01
and
a.DocDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
) 
,Invoice1 as (
        Select 
         DocEntry
        ,DocDate
        ,CardCode
        ,CardName
        ,U_CXS_FMST
        ,U_CXS_FRST
        ,U_DBS1StoreID
        ,CompleteStores
        ,StoreName
        ,CASE U_CXS_FRST
                    WHEN N'Y' THEN 1
                    WHEN N'N' THEN 0
                    ELSE 0
              END [iVend]
        ,     CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(U_DBS1StoreID,0)=0 THEN 0
                    WHEN ISNULL(U_DBS1StoreID,0)<>0 THEN 1
              END   [DBS]
        ,     CASE CardCode
                    WHEN N'C100' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END [Web]
                    ,CASE
                WHEN iVend = 0 AND DBS = 0 AND Web = 0
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END [Other]   
        ,NumAtCard
        ,U_TransactionID
        ,U_SalesSource
        ,Name
        ,LineNum
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,CstGrpCode
        ,U_WebName
        ,U_SupplierCatNum
        ,CatCode
        ,CatName
        ,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        ,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        ,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        ,DocTotal
        --,MarginPCT

        From Invoice    
        )
,Invoice2 as (      
    SELECT
        --DocEntry
         --DocDate
        --,CardCode
        --,CardName
        --,U_CXS_FMST
        --,U_CXS_FRST
        --,U_DBS1StoreID
        --,CompleteStores
          CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
          End SalesChnl   
          ,Case 
            When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 Then StoreName
            When Web = 1 Then Name --'Internet'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other' 
         End StoreName
        ,iVend
        ,DBS
        ,Web
        ,Other  
        --,NumAtCard
        --,U_TransactionID
        ,U_SalesSource
        ,Name
        --,LineNum
        --,CstGrpCode
        --,U_WebName
        --,U_SupplierCatNum
        --,CatCode
        ,CatName
        --,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        --,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        --,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        --,MarginPCT
        --,DocTotal         
FROM Invoice1   

--Where GrossBuyPr = 0

Group By
        --DocEntry
        --DocDate
        --,CardCode
        --,CardName
        --,U_CXS_FMST
        --,U_CXS_FRST
        --,U_DBS1StoreID
        --,CompleteStores
        CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
          End    
        ,Case 
            When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 Then StoreName
            When Web = 1 Then Name --'Internet'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
         End
        ,iVend
        ,DBS
        ,Web
        ,Other  
        --,NumAtCard
        --,U_TransactionID
        ,U_SalesSource
        ,Name
        --,LineNum
        --,CstGrpCode
        --,U_WebName
        --,U_SupplierCatNum
        --,CatCode
        ,CatName
        --,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        --,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        --,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        --,MarginPCT
        --,DocTotal   
        )
Select *
 from Invoice2
```

The only difference is this case expression where I try and use the Name column from the @salessource table instead of the string Internet.

```
,Case 
When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 Then StoreName
When Web = 1 Then Name --'Internet'
When Other = 1 then 'Other' 
 End StoreName
```

I've tried forcing collation and that had no effect.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by removing as much stuff as you can without losing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the final solution was to create a true #temp table to store the data from the two tables having the collation issues then join that table into the CTE of the main query.

The final code looks like this:

```
Declare @StartDate Date = '09/01/2013';
Declare @EndDate Date = Getdate();

Create Table #StoreTable (
SalesChnl Nvarchar(20),
StoreID Nvarchar(5),
StoreName Nvarchar(50));

insert into #StoreTable
SELECT 
'Web'
,[Code] 
,[Name]
FROM [@SALESSOURCE] 

insert into #StoreTable
Select   
'Retail'
,SiteId 
,Description
from CXSRetail.dbo.RtlStore;

With Invoice as (
        SELECT     
         a.DocEntry
        ,a.DocDate
        ,a.CardCode
        ,a.CardName
        ,a.U_CXS_FMST
        ,a.U_CXS_FRST
        ,a.U_DBS1StoreID
        ,CASE
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = 3 then 2
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = 4 then 3
            when a.DocDate >= '08/01/2011' then isnull(U_CXS_FMST,U_DBS1StoreID)
        end as CompleteStores
        ,CASE a.U_CXS_FRST
                    WHEN N'Y' THEN 1
                    WHEN N'N' THEN 0
                    ELSE 0
              END [iVend]
        ,     CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(a.U_DBS1StoreID,0)=0 THEN 0
                    WHEN ISNULL(a.U_DBS1StoreID,0)<>0 THEN 1
              END   [DBS]
        ,     CASE a.CardCode
                    WHEN N'C100' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END [Web]
        ,a.NumAtCard
        ,a.U_TransactionID
        ,a.U_SalesSource
        ,b.LineNum
        ,b.ItemCode
        ,c.ItemName
        ,c.CstGrpCode
        ,c.U_WebName
        ,c.U_SupplierCatNum
        ,c.CatCode
        ,c.CatName
        ,c.GroupCode
        ,c.GroupName
        ,c.DeptCode
        ,c.DeptName
        ,c.MfcCode
        ,c.Manufacturer
        ,Cast(b.Quantity as INT) Quantity
        ,b.Price
        ,b.PriceBefDi
        ,b.LineTotal
        ,b.GrossBuyPr
        ,a.DocTotal
        ,((Cast(b.Quantity as INT)* b.Price)-(Cast(b.Quantity as INT)*b.GrossBuyPr))/(Cast(b.Quantity as INT)*b.GrossBuyPr)*100 as MarginPCT

        FROM         
        MonkeySports.dbo.INV1 AS b 
        INNER JOIN 
        MonkeySports.dbo.OINV AS a ON a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
        Inner Join
        dbo.MS_OITM_Categories as c ON b.ItemCode = c.ItemCode
Where 
GrossBuyPr > 0.01
and
a.DocDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
) 
,Invoice1 as (
        Select 
         DocEntry
        ,DocDate
        ,CardCode
        ,CardName
        ,U_CXS_FMST
        ,U_CXS_FRST
        ,U_DBS1StoreID
        ,CompleteStores
        ,CASE U_CXS_FRST
                    WHEN N'Y' THEN 1
                    WHEN N'N' THEN 0
                    ELSE 0
              END [iVend]
        ,     CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(U_DBS1StoreID,0)=0 THEN 0
                    WHEN ISNULL(U_DBS1StoreID,0)<>0 THEN 1
              END   [DBS]
        ,     CASE CardCode
                    WHEN N'C100' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END [Web]
                    ,CASE
                WHEN iVend = 0 AND DBS = 0 AND Web = 0
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END [Other]   
        ,NumAtCard
        ,U_TransactionID
        ,U_SalesSource
        ,LineNum
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,CstGrpCode
        ,U_WebName
        ,U_SupplierCatNum
        ,CatCode
        ,CatName
        ,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        ,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        ,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        ,DocTotal
        ,MarginPCT

        From Invoice    
        )
,Invoice2 as (      
    SELECT
        DocEntry
         --DocDate
        --,CardCode
        --,CardName
        --,U_CXS_FMST
        --,U_CXS_FRST
        --,U_DBS1StoreID
        --,CompleteStores
          ,CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
          End SalesChnl   
        ,CASE 
             When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 then CompleteStores
             When Web = 1 OR Other = 1 then U_SalesSource
         End as StoreID  
         ,#StoreTable.StoreName    
        --,iVend
        --,DBS
        --,Web
        --,Other    
        --,NumAtCard
        --,U_TransactionID
        --,U_SalesSource
        --,Name
        --,LineNum
        --,CstGrpCode
        --,U_WebName
        --,U_SupplierCatNum
        --,CatCode
        ,CatName
        --,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        --,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        --,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        --,DocTotal         
        ,MarginPCT
FROM Invoice1 
inner join
#StoreTable on
CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Web'
          End  = #StoreTable.SalesChnl
AND           

CASE 
             When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 then CompleteStores
             When Web = 1 OR Other = 1 then U_SalesSource
         End = #StoreTable.StoreID

Group By
        DocEntry
        --DocDate
        --,CardCode
        --,CardName
        --,U_CXS_FMST
        --,U_CXS_FRST
        --,U_DBS1StoreID
        --,CompleteStores
        ,CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
          End    
         ,CASE 
             When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 then CompleteStores
             When Web = 1 OR Other = 1 then U_SalesSource
         End   
         ,#StoreTable.StoreName    
        --,iVend
        --,DBS
        --,Web
        --,Other    
        --,NumAtCard
        --,U_TransactionID
        --,U_SalesSource
        --,Name
        --,LineNum
        --,CstGrpCode
        --,U_WebName
        --,U_SupplierCatNum
        --,CatCode
        ,CatName
        --,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        --,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        --,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
      --,DocTotal   
        ,MarginPCT
        )
,CreditMemo as (
        SELECT     
         a.DocEntry
        ,a.DocDate
        ,a.CardCode
        ,a.CardName
        ,a.U_CXS_FMST
        ,a.U_CXS_FRST
        ,a.U_DBS1StoreID
        ,CASE
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = 3 then 2
            when a.DocDate < '08/01/2011' and U_DBS1StoreID = 4 then 3
            when a.DocDate >= '08/01/2011' then isnull(U_CXS_FMST,U_DBS1StoreID)
        end as CompleteStores
        ,CASE a.U_CXS_FRST
                    WHEN N'Y' THEN 1
                    WHEN N'N' THEN 0
                    ELSE 0
              END [iVend]
        ,     CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(a.U_DBS1StoreID,0)=0 THEN 0
                    WHEN ISNULL(a.U_DBS1StoreID,0)<>0 THEN 1
              END   [DBS]
        ,     CASE a.CardCode
                    WHEN N'C100' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END [Web]
        ,a.NumAtCard
        ,a.U_TransactionID
        ,a.U_SalesSource
        ,b.LineNum
        ,b.ItemCode
        ,c.ItemName
        ,c.CstGrpCode
        ,c.U_WebName
        ,c.U_SupplierCatNum
        ,c.CatCode
        ,c.CatName
        ,c.GroupCode
        ,c.GroupName
        ,c.DeptCode
        ,c.DeptName
        ,c.MfcCode
        ,c.Manufacturer
        ,(Cast(b.Quantity as INT)*-1) Quantity
        ,b.Price
        ,b.PriceBefDi
        ,b.LineTotal
        ,b.GrossBuyPr
        ,a.DocTotal
        ,((Cast(b.Quantity as INT)* b.Price)-(Cast(b.Quantity as INT)*b.GrossBuyPr))/(Cast(b.Quantity as INT)*b.GrossBuyPr)*100 as MarginPCT

        FROM         
        MonkeySports.dbo.RIN1 AS b 
        INNER JOIN 
        MonkeySports.dbo.ORIN AS a ON a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
        Inner Join
        dbo.MS_OITM_Categories as c ON b.ItemCode = c.ItemCode
Where 
GrossBuyPr > 0.01
and
a.DocDate between @StartDate and @EndDate       
) 
,CreditMemo1 as (
        Select 
         DocEntry
        ,DocDate
        ,CardCode
        ,CardName
        ,U_CXS_FMST
        ,U_CXS_FRST
        ,U_DBS1StoreID
        ,CompleteStores
        ,CASE U_CXS_FRST
                    WHEN N'Y' THEN 1
                    WHEN N'N' THEN 0
                    ELSE 0
              END [iVend]
        ,     CASE 
                    WHEN ISNULL(U_DBS1StoreID,0)=0 THEN 0
                    WHEN ISNULL(U_DBS1StoreID,0)<>0 THEN 1
              END   [DBS]
        ,     CASE CardCode
                    WHEN N'C100' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END [Web]
                    ,CASE
                WHEN iVend = 0 AND DBS = 0 AND Web = 0
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END [Other]   
        ,NumAtCard
        ,U_TransactionID
        ,U_SalesSource
        ,LineNum
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,CstGrpCode
        ,U_WebName
        ,U_SupplierCatNum
        ,CatCode
        ,CatName
        ,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        ,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        ,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        ,DocTotal
        ,MarginPCT

        From CreditMemo 
        )
,CreditMemo2 as (       
    SELECT
        DocEntry
         --DocDate
        --,CardCode
        --,CardName
        --,U_CXS_FMST
        --,U_CXS_FRST
        --,U_DBS1StoreID
        --,CompleteStores
          ,CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
          End SalesChnl   
         ,CASE 
             When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 then CompleteStores
             When Web = 1 OR Other = 1 then U_SalesSource
         End as StoreID  
         ,#StoreTable.StoreName  
        --,iVend
        --,DBS
        --,Web
        --,Other    
        --,NumAtCard
        --,U_TransactionID
        --,U_SalesSource
        --,Name
        --,LineNum
        --,CstGrpCode
        --,U_WebName
        --,U_SupplierCatNum
        --,CatCode
        ,CatName
        --,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        --,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        --,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        --,DocTotal         
        ,MarginPCT
FROM CreditMemo1
inner join
#StoreTable on
CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Web'
          End  = #StoreTable.SalesChnl
AND           
CASE 
             When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 then CompleteStores
             When Web = 1 OR Other = 1 then U_SalesSource
         End = #StoreTable.StoreID
Group By
        DocEntry
        --DocDate
        --,CardCode
        --,CardName
        --,U_CXS_FMST
        --,U_CXS_FRST
        --,U_DBS1StoreID
        --,CompleteStores
        ,CASE
            When iVend = 1 or DBS = 1 then 'Retail'
            When Web = 1 then 'Web'
            When Other = 1 then 'Other'
          End    
        ,CASE 
             When iVend = 1 OR DBS = 1 then CompleteStores
             When Web = 1 OR Other = 1 then U_SalesSource
         End    
         ,#StoreTable.StoreName  
        --,iVend
        --,DBS
        --,Web
        --,Other    
        --,NumAtCard
        --,U_TransactionID
        --,Name
        --,U_SalesSource
        --,LineNum
        --,CstGrpCode
        --,U_WebName
        --,U_SupplierCatNum
        --,CatCode
        ,CatName
        --,GroupCode
        ,GroupName
        --,DeptCode
        ,DeptName
        --,MfcCode
        ,Manufacturer
        ,ItemCode
        ,ItemName
        ,Quantity
        ,Price
        ,PriceBefDi
        ,LineTotal
        ,GrossBuyPr
        --,DocTotal   
        ,MarginPCT
        )

Select *
from 
Invoice2  
Union 

Select *
from 
CreditMemo2  
Order by 
MarginPCT Desc
,SalesChnl
,StoreName
,CatName
,DeptName

DROP TABLE #StoreTable
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Take out column and get to the query in a state where its not throwing an error then start adding columns one by one and where it throws an error check with other column it is relating to and add something like this in your query in `WHERE Clause`

```
WHERE Table1.Collation1Col COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = Table2.Collation2Col COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

For further investigation check column in your table where Collation is different from other column. using

```
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'U'
AND name = 'table_Name')
```

It will narrow down your search for the culprits.

Comment: So I narrowed down the issue. it appears that of the two tables that are in collation conflict one is using an INT as the filed the I'm linking on and the other table is using an nvarchar for it's linking field.

When I tried casting them to the same (either int or Nvarchar) I get the error can't use INT for collate. GRRRRR

So I came up with the idea of using a Table variable and populating it with the values from both conflicting tables. So far So good.

However I can't seem to get the table variable to be recognized by the CTE. 

How can I do that?

Comment: Where you joining the tables just convert the FK column to the PK column Data type something like ...

ON Table1.ID = CAST(Table2.Column AS INT)

Comment: I tried that and it gave me the error can't collate on an (INT)

And since I can't use a @table variable with a CTE. I had to create a true temp table. So now I need to figure out how to join the #temp table to the CTE. 

The #temp table has a two part key since the storeID can be duplicated (they come from different source systems and I'm stumped.